# Adding vectors with sequential names to a table using a for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector

I have vectors (each with 1 row and 13 columns) that are named sequentially (values.val0001, values.val0002, etc.), I am trying to input all of these vectors as rows in one table using the follwing code:

```
for i = 1:50;
    j = sprintf('%04d', i);
m = [];
m =[m; values.(['val' j])];
end
```

The above code will only produce a table with the first row (i.e. values.val0001) and wouldnt input the sequentialy named vectors (i.e. values.val0002, values.val0003) to subsequent rows as I intend.

Comment: Where have these variables come from?  Why didn't you just use an array (matrix) rather than loads of individual variables?

Comment: These variables were achieved using multiple steps, first I had to import seqentially named .dat files and then curve-fit the values in the files sequentially to produce the variables I present here. The only way to organise them (give them sequential names) was to put them in structures.

Comment: Each variable (e.g. values.val0001) is a vector with 1 row and 13 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the row with `m = []` out of the for loop, otherwise you will reset the variable **m** each time